# Syncing with Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sap-iq

We have 20TB data on Sybase IQ. It is our primary server. However, it cannot support multiple applications which does intensive querying.

In order to support above requirement, we are planning to port data to Amazon Redshift which will be used for querying purposes.

What would be the best way to keep Redshift in sync with Sybase IQ?

Are there options better suited than Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a **3rd-party tool** that can ETL the data from Sybase into Amazon Redshift.

You could write an integration yourself to dump data from Sybase and then load it into Redshift, but if you want it does on a continuing basis, it would be easier to use a proper tool.

A web search reveals:

- [Sybase and Amazon Redshift Integration – Database Query Component](https://www.matillion.com/etl-for-redshift/integrations/sybase/)
- [High-performance Data Loading for SAP Sybase IQ for Extreme-scale Enterprise Data Warehousing and Big Data | Attunity](https://www.attunity.com/content/data-warehouse-solutions-for-sap-sybase-iq/)